# Creating and transferring a site with Django

Tags: python, django

As a fledgling Django developer, I was wondering if it was customary, or indeed possible, to create a site with Django then transfer the complete file structure to a different machine where it would "go live".

Thanks,

~Caitlin

Comment: Yes and no. Depends on the situation. But, customarily, it can be "yes".

Comment: `settings.py` has several vars to [parametrize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/) ( as DEGUG, MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL, DATABASES, PORT, ALLOWED_HOSTS, ...) this operation. Also you have [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/). Only take in mind a method to assign a `settings.py` for each environment.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Of course it's possible: how else would you do it? You would want to do your development on your production machine.

Answer (score 3):

You could use GIT or Mercurial - or other version control system. To put the site structure on a central server. After that you could deploy the site for example with fabric to multiple servers. For deployment process you should consider using for example virtualenv to isolate the project from global python packages and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that's possible and in fact it's the only way to "go live". You don't want to develop in your live server, do you? And it's true for any platform, not just django.

If I understood your question correctly, you need a system to push your development code to live.

- Use a version control system: git, svn, mercurial etc.
- Identify environment specific code like setting/config files etc. and have separate instances of them for each environment.
- Create a testing/staging/PP environment which has live data or live-like data and deploy your code there before pushing it to live.
- To avoid any downtime during deployment process, usually a symbolic link is created which points to the existing code folder. When a new release is to be pushed, a new folder is created with new code, after all other dependencies are done (like setting and database changes) and the sym link is pointed to the new folder.